# chrome warning | Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is depreciated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

The purpose of a synchronous XMLHttpRequest (**sxhr**) is it's depreciation that chrome claims. **sxhr**'s solve problems that otherwise can not be solved using asynchronous calls. Example, the need of a return of a variable outside a asynchronous function. Asynchronous and synchronous methods are entirely different, in fact, they are opposite; So, claiming a method is depreciated by an opposite method is entirely irrational.

I would like to ignore this warning in my framework.

synchronous calls should only be called when necessary, my situation is necessary.

Comment: _"the need of a return of a variable outside a asynchronous function"_. Sounds like _that_ is your actual problem, not the deprecation of of sxhr.

Comment: And that problem was solved using sync methods.

Comment: I doubt that it couldn't be solved using the async version, though =D

Comment: OK, so you've made a big statement about how you can't be bothered to write code that uses callbacks, and are going to provide a horrible blocking experience instead. So what? This isn't a blog. Did you have a question?

Comment: I encourage you to rethink your architecture.  It is entirely possible to achieve whatever you want using asynchronous technologies.  But asynchronous programming is a different way of thinking and architecting, so I encourage you to not dismiss asynchronous because synchronous methods seem to simplify your code.

Comment: Nobody keeps you from ignoring warnings. What is your question?

Comment: @Quentin I am trying to block the chrome flag from showing up in developer console.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [current XHR spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) (see yellow note), Chrome is not at fault. Synchronous XHRs are in the process of deprecation on the web platform scale, so you should definitely migrate your application to [async XHRs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).